# How to implement nice animation for rectangle UIButton to circle shape in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

When i clicked on "Login" button i need to make my rectangle login button
[Login Screenshot](http://s1.postimg.org/jlk1z8mv3/Screen_Shot_2015_09_11_at_10_51_38_am.png)
to animate and change it shape to circle like below link
[Login Button after i click](http://s17.postimg.org/4a5ggi41b/Screen_Shot_2015_09_11_at_10_54_35_am.png)

I have seen this code in stackoverflow but its not working the way i want

```
    CGFloat width = self.login.frame.size.width;
CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
morph.fromValue = @0;
morph.toValue = @(width/2);
morph.duration = 0.5;
[self.login.layer addAnimation:morph forKey:@"morph"];
self.login.layer.cornerRadius = width/2;
```

Please help

Thanks for answering this.

This is the final code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         self.layoutWidth.constant = 70;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         self.btnLogin.clipsToBounds = YES;
                         self.btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius =self.btnLogin.bounds.size.height/2.0f;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

[Demo Animation](http://ge.tt/2KVYYjN2/v/0)

Code:

```
- (IBAction)clicklogin:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         self.layoutWidth.constant = 70;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                         NSLog(@"Done!");

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.btnLogin.clipsToBounds = YES;
                                              self.btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius =self.btnLogin.bounds.size.height/2.0f; //or use ( self.login.bounds.size.height/2);
                                              self.btnLogin.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                                              self.btnLogin.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

                                              [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){


                                              NSLog(@"Done!");

                                          }];


                     }];

}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Download code of demo, it is layout of width of button,

Comment: Demo Animation download and Study it

Comment: ok, i understood. its working also thanks but one doubt can i make litle delay to see the transition from rectangle to circle. i tried to change animation delay u have given in code but not effecting that timing

Comment: delay 1.0, when click on button then after 1.0 it start animation, and second delay 0.0 because animation keep continue, don't required delay so put 0.0,

Comment: i have made some changes in  your code and its working cool now ,please check updated code in

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = btn.frame;
        CGPoint center = btn.center;
        frame.size.width = btn.frame.size.height;
        frame.size.height = btn.frame.size.height;

        btn.frame = frame;
        btn.center = center;
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2;
        btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

    }];
```

This is what i get
[image]

And after a 1 sec animation i get this

[image]

Comment: unfortunately your code also not working  http://s13.postimg.org/6y6t2y5rr/image.png

Comment: Should work now, i miswrote the corner radius as the height, where it will be width.

Comment: i edited the corner radius from height to width/2 and its working for me quite nicely as u can see the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get circle,just follow simple way

```
-(IBAction)actionClick:(id)sender
{  
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                 animations:^
  {
     [sender setAlpha:0.5f];
  }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {
     [sender setAlpha:1.0f];
     button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
     button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
     button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
    ];
  }
}
```